# SESSION не изменяется

Tags: php, сессия

Через `fetch` в файл `сore.php` отправляется `action`, который  равен `'login'`, а так же `email` и `epass`.

вот содержимое core.php:

```html
<?php
    session_start();//session
    cors();

    // auto load classes
    spl_autoload_register(function ($class_name) {
        include './classes/' . $class_name . '.php';
    });

    // what to choose 
    if(isset($_POST['action'])) $action = $_POST['action']; 

    $conn   = new Connect();
    $render = new Render($action);

    switch ($action) {
        case 'profile':
            if(isset($_SESSION['authorization'])){
                $action = 'prof';
                echo $action;
            }else{
                $action = 'login';
                echo $action;
            }
            // var_dump($_SESSION); -- array(0)
            break;
        case 'login':
            $emailLogin   = $_POST['email'];
            $passLogin    = $_POST['epass'];
            $doLogin = new Login($emailLogin, $passLogin);
            try {
                $doLogin->login();
                // Если true
                echo true;
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }
            break;
    } 

    function cors() {
        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {
            header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']}");
            header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
            header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400');
        }

        if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {

            if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD']))
                header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS");         

            if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']))
                header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']}");
        }
    }
?>
```

Здесь выполняется метод login();

Вот содержимое класса login

```html
<?php
    require_once('connect.php');

    class Login extends Connect{
        public function __construct($email, $pass){ 
            $this->email = $email;
            $this->pass = $pass;
        }
        public function login(){
            $conn = parent::conn();

            $userDB = $conn->query("SELECT mail FROM users WHERE mail = '$this->email'");
            if($userDB->num_rows == 1){
                $hash = $conn->query("SELECT password FROM users WHERE mail = '$this->email'");
                $hash = $hash->fetch_assoc();
                if(password_verify($this->pass, $hash['password'])){
                    $userId = $conn->query("SELECT userId FROM users WHERE mail = '$this->email'");
                    $userId = $userId->fetch_assoc();
                    $_SESSION['userId'] = $userId['userId'];
                    $_SESSION['authorization'] = true;
                    // var_dump($_SESSION); -- array(2) {
                                                    // ["userId"]=>
                                                    // string(2) "21"
                                                    // ["authorization"]=>
                                                    // bool(true)
                                                // }
                    return true;
                }else throw new Exception('Неверный пароль');
            }else throw new Exception('Такой пользователь не найден');
        }
    }
?>
```

Здесь создается сессия, а потом она дампается, результат дампа виден в комментарии.
Но проблема в том, что дамп сессии в файле core.php возвращает array(0)

Comment: Вероятно у вас session_start вызывается где-то ещё. Проверьте чтобы везде перед её вызовом делалась проверка на isset($_SESSION); также используйте пошаговую отладку чтобы видеть значения переменных.

Answer (score 0):

Оказалось, что php не в чем не виноват, виноват js и его пароноик fetch, который не отправляется кукисы, чтобы это исправить нужно написать в опции `fetch` 
`credentials: 'include'`
и всё!